# Rails: Using friendly_id/slug with column from associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

I've got Contact model which I want to be slugged (friendly_id gem). By using the user_name column from User model which Contact model belongs to.

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id self.user.user_name, use: :slugged
```

But typing `Contact.find_each(&:save)` in my rails console I get this error:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `user' for Contact (call
>   'Contact.connection' to establish a connection):Class)

How can I use my assosiated model as a slug?

Rails version: 5.2.2
Friendly_id gem: 5.2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FriendlyId always uses a method as the basis of the slug text, for your problem above I think you create method for user_name and call related field inside a method

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :user_name

  def user_name
    user.user_name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this way:

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :user_name

  def user_name
    user.user_name
  end
end
```